# How to select rows according to column value conditions

Tags: r

I have a data set which looks like the following (partially):

```
id  name    dummy
1   Jane    1
1   Jane    0
1   Jane    1
2   Mike    0
2   Mike    0
2   Mike    0
2   Mike    0
2   Mike    0
3   Tom     1
3   Tom     1
3   Tom     0
3   Tom     0
```

I'm trying to eliminate the people where ALL of the variable `dummy` is 0. So for instance, `Tom` and `Jane` would not be eliminated because they have `dummy` variable 0 or 1, but `Mike` will be eliminated because he has all 0s. So I would want in the end

```
   id   name    dummy
    1   Jane    1
    1   Jane    0
    1   Jane    1
    3   Tom     1
    3   Tom     1
    3   Tom     0
    3   Tom     0
```

I thought about sorting the data frame according to `dummy` but I can't seem to figure out how to deal with the fact that I'm only trying to eliminate the people who only has 0 values for the variable `dummy`. Any suggestions would be really helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider `df` is your data.frame, then use `tapply` and `[` to subset what you want:

```
> ind <- with(df, tapply(dummy, name, sum))
> df[df$name %in% names(ind)[ind!=0], ]
   id name dummy
1   1 Jane     1
2   1 Jane     0
3   1 Jane     1
9   3  Tom     1
10  3  Tom     1
11  3  Tom     0
12  3  Tom     0
```

Another alternative:

```
> result <- split(df, df$name)[with(df, tapply(dummy, name, function(x) sum(x)!=0))]
> do.call(rbind, result)
```

Comment: +1 Personally I think `split` on a `df` would be a bad choice as it tends to be terribly slow as the number of unique *levels* to split by increases.. Ex: `df <- data.frame(x=sample(1e4, 1e7, TRUE), y=1:1e7); system.time(split(df, df$x))`...

Comment: Yes :). It took 380 seconds using `split` in the example above. It takes 5 seconds doing: `system.time(ans <- dt[, list(list(.SD)), by=x, .SDcols=c("x", "y")]$V1)`

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I ask what %in% is doing?

Comment: `%in%` returns a logical vector indicating if there is a match or not for its left operand. [See `?"%in%"`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) for further details.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
subset(dat, as.logical(ave(dummy, id, FUN = any)))

#    id name dummy
# 1   1 Jane     1
# 2   1 Jane     0
# 3   1 Jane     1
# 9   3  Tom     1
# 10  3  Tom     1
# 11  3  Tom     0
# 12  3  Tom     0
```

An alternative with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, if (any(dummy)) .SD, by = id]
```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(any(dummy))
```

Answer (score 1):

`ave` can be used to produce the groupwise sum, while keeping the original position:

```
x[with(x, ave(dummy, name, FUN=sum))>0,]
##    id name dummy
## 1   1 Jane     1
## 2   1 Jane     0
## 3   1 Jane     1
## 9   3  Tom     1
## 10  3  Tom     1
## 11  3  Tom     0
## 12  3  Tom     0
```

`ave` is something like `aggregate` but copies the aggregated value for each row in the set:

```
with(x, ave(dummy, name, FUN=sum))
## [1] 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `plyr::ddply` too

```
require(plyr)
ddply(df, .(name), function(x) subset(x, !all(dummy == 0)))
##   id name dummy
## 1  1 Jane     1
## 2  1 Jane     0
## 3  1 Jane     1
## 4  3  Tom     1
## 5  3  Tom     1
## 6  3  Tom     0
## 7  3  Tom     0
```

Note that it's possible to replace `!all(dummy == 0)` by `any(dummy != 0)`